Chrome and Edge browsers have both stopped opening a file selector
I am not sure exactly what has happened and all I can find is how to change the default file explorer. Even on this website I can't open the file browser to upload images. I also cannot save images to my computer from the browser. However pasting them in does work.


I am using Pop_OS and installed their new COSMIC desktop, which I suspect is where the problem started. When I switch to COSMIC opening the file browser works fine. Also, Firefox works just fine also.
My real question is how do I manipulate this setting? What is the underlying setting that determines how Chrome opens the file browser?
EDIT: I forgot to mention I am using i3wm on Pop_OS

Does this help? Let me know: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73695994

It looks like the same problem however the accepted solution doesn't work for me. I have installed

it definitely has something to do with xdg-desktop-portals but just installing the portals it needs is not fixing the problem. i think when i installed COSMIC it reconfigured some settings and i can't figure out where to change them
